# fractinal number to CSD reprasentation

Tags: matlab

Can any one have matlab code for the fractional number to canonical sign digit conversion?
or binary to canonical sign digit conversion.

I got the matlab code for decimal to csd conversion from matlab file exchange. But i want to convert fractional number to csd.

csd=canonical sign digit

Comment: did you try something by yourself?

Comment: I tried to convert it into cell and trying to write csd algorithm for binary to csd. but its too lengthy process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can download csdigit file from
http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/9730-canonical-signed-digits

In that u just replace dec2bin to Fr_dec2bin  and viseversa.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this: [CSD](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/9730-canonical-signed-digits/content/csdigit.m)

Example:

```
 example [a,p,n]=csdigit(23.5,6,2) returns 
            a = +0-000.-0 
            p=32 
            n=8.5 
            23.5 = 32 - 8 - 0.5
```

Comment: But sit it don't work for 0.13  or number <1.  I made some changes in the main csd file and it gives me some approximate answer but not the accurate.